# Phonegap app "Installing..." loop on iOS 7

Tags: cordova, ios7

I'm having problems installing a Phonegap app on my iPhone 4S. When I try to install it, it certainly starts the installation and finishes but after 3 or 5 seconds it starts "installing..." again.

I've 2 Phonegap apps installed on this Phone and I don't know what is happening with the new one. Any clues?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Phonegap Build you're gonna need

1) certificate (p12) file
2) provisioning profile

When you generate the provisioning profile it asks you to choose a certificate. My mistake was to pick a different certificate on 2) that the one I used on the 1) because of the name.

Answer (score 1):

At this time (10/19/13) PGB still doesn't support iOS7.  Cordova 3.1 was released on 10/2/13 and they're still working on implementing it to PGBuild.

See this thread :

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/inconsistent_ios_7_status_bar_build_problem#reply_13099221

It's kind of shocking this wasn't thought of months ago.